# def __str__(self) being ignored in Django admin

Tags: python, django, model

I have the following model defined:

from django.db import models

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    BIRTH_GENDERS = (
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('U', 'Unknown')
    )

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=BIRTH_GENDERS)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.last_name
```

On the Django admin panel it is showing Patient Object(1), no the last name. Can not figure out what is going wrong, no errors in the command line.

Comment: Are you sure `def __str__(self)` is indented correctly underneath the `Patient` class?

Comment: yes, it is indented correctly as far as I know (single indent inline with the rest of the class)

Comment: as far as I remember admin is using `__repr__`

Comment: Make sure the debug runserver or whatever else you're using picked up the change. If not, the old code will continue running.

Comment: tried __repr__ and restarted the server, still showing Patient Object(1)

Comment: Try deleting the compiled `*.pyc` files and `__pycache__` folders and restart the server.

Comment: deleted the files and restarted the server, no change

Comment: Likely causes being ruled out, let’s go with unlikely: is the last name in the db “Patient Object(1)”? Maybe placeholder data was used or something. Try returning a different string or field, and check admin. Or try a syntax error and see if it notices at all (file may be a different version?). Use the Django shell and try to print the object there. Use print statements to debug to console.